# Spark evicting storage memory beyond the limit defined by spark.memory.storageFraction

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a small pyspark experiment on a dataproc cluster. I am not able to put together the dynamic memory allocation with what I am observing in the sparkUI

cluster configuration (directly from the env tab of the sparkUI):

```
spark.executor.instances = 4
spark.executor.memory = 6G
spark.executor.memoryOverHead = 2G
spark.executor.pyspark.memory = 2G
spark.memory.fraction = 0.6
spark.memory.offHeap.size = 2G
spark.memory.storageFraction = 0.5
```

So, my immune to eviction part of the heap is (accounting for 300 MB reserved memory)

```
(6*(1024)-300)*0.6*0.5
1753.2 MBs per executor
```

Since I have 4 executors, my overall heap immune to eviction should be

```
1753.2*4
7012.8 MBs or 6.85 GBs
```

Now, I read in a dataset (It is around 9.5 GB) and put it in the cache

```
df_sales = spark.read.option("format","parquet").option("header",True).option("inferSchema",True).load("gs://monsoon-credittech.appspot.com/spark_datasets/sales_parquet")
from pyspark import StorageLevel
df_sales = df_sales.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
df_sales.count()
```

My storage tab in the spark UI shows that I have been able to put all of the data in the memory and no disk spill occurred. It has just one row (expected) for the `df_sales`

```
Storage Level: Disk Memory Serialized 1x Replicated
Cached Partitions 83
Fraction Cached 100%
Size in Memory 9.5 GiB
Size on Disk 0.0B
```

Now, the part of the storage that is immune to eviction (6.5 GBs) should never be overtaken by execution unless I unpersist some data and make that memory available.

To test that I ran an operation that uses heavy execution memory (join) and then persisted the output and checked how the persisted output got divided between the disk and the memory. I used `StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK`

This is how I am doing it:

```
df_sales_copy = spark.read.option("format","parquet").option("header",True).option("inferSchema",True).load("gs://monsoon-credittech.appspot.com/spark_datasets/sales_parquet")
df_merged = df_sales.join(df_sales_copy,df_sales.order_id==df_sales_copy.order_id,'inner')
df_merged = df_merged.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
df_merged.count()
```

**Now, my storage tab shows me numbers that I cannot make sense of. The eviction should never have reduced the storage memory below 6.85 GBs. However, the storage shows that it is reduced to `3.5 GBs`**. The storage tab now has two rows (expected), one for `df_sales` and the other for the `df_merged`

```
df_sales: 
Storage Level: Disk Memory Serialized 1x Replicated
Cached Partitions 83
Fraction Cached 100%
Size in Memory 0.0 B #evicted as earlier it was 9.5 GiB
Size on Disk 9.5 GiB

df_merged:
Storage Level: Disk Memory Serialized 1x Replicated
Cached Partitions 200
Fraction Cached 100%
Size in Memory 3.4 GiB
Size on Disk 15.8 GiB
```

I have not called unpersist anywhere then why is spark allowed to evict memory below the hard threshold set by `spark.memory.storageFraction`